# Why cant I find my cookies in Temporary Internet Files?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I'm trying to convert a cookie from `www.example.com` to `.example.com`.

So I thought I'd go to C:\Users\SWEAVER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files and just delete the cookie there.

To my surprise there were not only no temporary internet files (images/html...) but also very few cookies. And of course the cookie for my site was nowhere to be seen. However it is DEFINITELY working becasue I'm storing a GUID in there and that GUID was recoverable across different `iexplore.exe` processes.

I just went ahead and cleared cookies + temp files and now theres not a single file in my temp internet files directory - yet cookies ARE working for both my site and among others stackoverflow!

i did have a couple wierd bluescreens the other day - and in fact my event system log was corrupted. but i'm not sure if thats anythin to do with it?

I've run out of ideas but id really lke to be able to clear my application's cookies easily without screwing up my everyday cookies. Anybody got any idea about this or seen the problem before?

System : 2008 Server with IE7

Comment: because i'm trying to program

Comment: Cookies are stored in multiple places. Vista has 3 places. Look here:

http://www.dutchduck.com/help/Cookies%20Explorer/FAQ/Where%20are%20cookies%20stored.htm

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are stored in multiple places. Vista has 3 places. Look here:

http://www.dutchduck.com/help/Cookies%20Explorer/FAQ/Where%20are%20cookies%20stored.htm – BobbyShaftoe