# File system storage/access to IE cookies

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, http, web-applications, cookies

is there any way to list/decode cookies stored by Internet Explorer, w/o running the browser?

I am now tinkering with SWT Browser component which provides get/set methods for cookies, but is there any way to see what is really stored by IE itself?

**UPD**: I am using IE7. This location:
C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files
does not contain cookies if I look at the place with Far Manager.

Apparently Explorer mixes them in from some other location or database. Any ideas?

**UPD2**: Okay, okay. This is my current problem. Some webapp does not work if I restart IE7 and load the same page again (lots of scripting, embedded flash and video streaming). Killing the cookies seems to help, if we do that from within the IE itself. If we programmatically kill the cookies (listed by name) it does not help and page gets stuck on restart/reload sequence.

If I manually wipe the cache folder it indeed helps and subsequent page loads work fine. So the question is - do I really wipe the cookies while wiping the Temporary Internet Files folder or not? I just need to know the cause - is it resource cache or some cookie which we don't list in the cleanup sequence.

Comment: Raw file system access. Javascript does what I need from within the browser, but I just think of some more brutal/direct access possibility.

Comment: Oh, this dev had a problem finding cookie storage as I am currently quite interested in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310925/why-cant-i-find-my-cookies-in-temporary-internet-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh... quite a simple question, why noone was willing to answer?

Looks like explorer shows files from c:\Documents and Settings\USER\Cookies mixed in into Temporary Internet Files. This was XP, not sure how other versions behave.

Answer (score 0):

[source](http://firstbestanswer.com/question/adcel/temporary-internet-files-folder-windows.html)

Temporary Internet Files is a pretend folder. The view you see in Explorer is a combination of the actual files on disk, which live in securly unpredictably named subfolders, and the Wininet Url Cache Containers that store the metadata about the files (like what URL they came from, expiry date, etc). If you use filesystem APIs, you'll get what's actually there. If you use shell APIs, however, you can enumerate them in the way you want. Try starting with SHParseDisplayName() and go from there.